# Using gdallocationinfo on a rotated SAR image to get pixel value at coordinates

Tags: raster, arcmap, gdal, ground-control, sar

Some information: I must not re-sample the image, the pixels are rotated, and the image opens in ArcMap just fine.
now, there are 15 GCPs on the raster (which make the pixels rotate)

Progress:
1.When I first try to use `gdallocationinfo` I get:
ERROR 6: No translation for an empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known.

2.I use `gdal_edit -ro -a_srs epsg:4326 "Image"`, this creates a .aux.xml file with the same name as my image, GDAL now reads them both together, image still works on ArcMap.  Then I use `gdallocationinfo` again and get:

```
ERROR 1: Cannot get geotransform
```

3.I use `gcps2wld "Image"` to get the geotransformation parameters, and insert it to the .aux.xml file via Python GDAL `dataset.SetGeoTransform`

now ArcMap can't read the image, and when I use `gdalinfo`, I get the following:

> Corner Coordinates:
> Upper Left  (   0.0000360,  -0.0000277) (  0d 0' 0.13"E,  0d 0' 0.10"S)
> Lower Left  (      -0.145,  887589.718) (  0d 8'43.59"W,Invalid angle)
> Upper Right (      -0.068,-1152505.040) (  0d 4' 3.91"W,Invalid angle)
> Lower Right (      -0.213, -264915.321) (  0d12'47.63"W,Invalid angle)
> Center      (      -0.107, -132457.661) (  0d 6'23.75"W,Invalid angle)

and if I Ignore that and use `gdallocationinfo`, coordinates that are supposed to be in the image give me errors for being outside the image borders.

I tried using `gdal_edit -a_ullr` to set the corner coordinates, but that just norths up the image (no rotation).

How do I set up the image right (without resampling) so I can get the right pixels in the right coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the cause of the problem. I got the order of the geotransformation parameters wrong.

> the georeferencing transform takes the following form :

```
adfGeoTransform[0] /* top left x */
adfGeoTransform[1] /* w-e pixel resolution */
adfGeoTransform[2] /* 0 */
adfGeoTransform[3] /* top left y */
adfGeoTransform[4] /* 0 */
adfGeoTransform[5] /* n-s pixel resolution (negative value) */
```

I hope this helps anyone!